# The differences between the reporting clause and the reported clause

Tags: reported-speech

As the title says, I am quite confused about the reporting clause and the reported clause. What are the characters and different uses, and how do I identify which clause belongs to the reporting clause or reported clause? Please feel free to provide some examples and illustrations.
For example, 1. ‘You're right, it isn't a good idea.' - He agreed that it wasn't a good idea. 2. ‘I disagree. It's not a good idea at all.' - He didn't agree that it was a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "reporting" clause is the matrix clause. It will use a verb like "say", "think" or here "agree".  The reported clause is the subordinate clause. It will usually be marked with the subordinator "that".

So the reporting clause is "He agreed {...}". And the reported clause is "(that) it wasn't a good idea"